# Show/Don't Show Remove Button for Edit/New Page

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

This is pretty simple.  I have a UWP application that has a page with a Save button and an Edit button (call it Page1).  The page that the buttons take you to (Page2) is exactly the same, except when the user clicks Edit, Page2 has a Remove button and when the user clicks Save, Page2 does NOT have a Remove button.

I am already sending a parameter to Page2 in the saveBtn_Click and editBtn_Click methods:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), param1);
```

and figured I could also send a true/false depending on the button clicked.  Since this was 2 parameters, I thought to create a Payload class with these values assigned to member variables and then send a Payload object (payload).  Then, in the OnNavigatedTo method of Page2's code behind, I can set a variable (visible) to the value of payload.visible and set the button's visibility property to this value.

However, I am thinking that there has to be a more elegant way to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is good there are someways to do that. 
The most common way is using OnNabigatedTo and OnNabigatedFrom to send parameters. If you are using MVVM you can use Messages or payloads between viewmodels.
Another way is using an static class to save this variables.
Well in this case I think your solution is fine